# Watch expression in dartium 36 cannot traverse List

Tags: dart, dartium

I cannot see a list of values in class List of dart code in Watch Expression panel of dartium 36 dev tools. Shown

[[class]]: List
==: bool operator ...
etc.

Is there any way to traverse list? I can write list[0], list[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG59m.jpg) etc., but it is terrible solution.

There is javascript Array view at the top of image and dartium List view behind.

[image: Watch expression screenshot]

Comment: I think this was a bug that is already fixed.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? Recently Dart 1.5.8 was released. Did you try after the update?

Comment: Dartium version 36.0.1985.97 (280598), Windows - still the same problem. Downloaded today from https://www.dartlang.org/tools/download.html

Comment: I have bleeding edge with Dartium version 37.0.2062.0 (287872) (64-bit) maybe this fix is not yet included in stable.

Comment: Please add a link, if somewhere is dartium 37 compiled for windows. This feature is more important than stability.

Comment: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/download.html look for `early adopter` and `Dev Channel`. It's not bleeding edge but only a few days behind. I guess this should do.

Comment: 37.0.2062.0 (286245) on Windows still the same problem

Comment: Than you should create a bug report at dartbug.com.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20447&thanks=20447&ts=1407667407